# get third party website url

Tags: laravel, http-referer

After i checkout my page redirect into payment gateway website. After successfully paid or fail, its redirect (POST method) into my own website page (www.abc.com/success/id or www.abc.com/fail/id).

My question is can i get that payment gateway website url. I want to know from which url i am redirected.

I am using Laravel5.6 and my code looks like this

```
public function getPaymentSuccess(Request $request){
  $get_payment_gateway_url = URL::previous();
  dd($get_payment_gateway_url);
}
```

its printed current url only (my own website url).

Answer (score 0):

If the payment gateway is willing to share where it redirected from, either because it generated a redirect response which the browser followed and set the originator, or because it directly called the callback URL and supplied a referer, then you can access this information from:

```
$get_payment_gateway_url = $request->server("HTTP_REFERER");
```

However this being an `HTTP_*` header means that it's supplied by the originator of the request and therefore should not be used for security checks nor is it guaranteed that it will be there.

If the payment gateway does not share this information then it is impossible to know where the request is coming from because this usually happens outside your server and the only thing your server sees is just an incoming request with whatever information the originator decided to provide.

Comment: when i used $request->server("HTTP_REFERER") its printed null. that means payment gateway not share information?

Comment: That's likely to be the case